# Why would sbt reload gen-idea use 6GB of memory?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm using the command

```
sbt reload gen-idea
```

to build a largish (hundreds of thousands of lines of code) IntelliJ Scala project.

After about 30 minutes+, the program is autokilled because it runs out of memory. I checked, and it used 6GB before getting killed.

What's going on? Can I do anything to improve this?

Sorry I can't add more details: I know almost nothing about SBT.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually using reload iwth sbt is useless, cause reload command reloads your Build configuration in the opened sbt session and when you r launching sbt from command line, it will automaticaly read the last version of your config files. As for the time i guess that's the problem with the plugin. Try to add `SBT_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"` into your /.sbtconfig file, that will limit the amount of memory used by sbt.